# Elastic Search giving inconsistent result

Tags: elasticsearch, elk

I have an elastic search query that gives me unfiletered result set of 5 records.
Ulfiltered Query:

```
{
    "from": 0,
    "size": 250,
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "term": {
                        "status": {
                            "value": "Active",
                            "boost": 1.0
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "match_phrase_prefix": {
                        "primaryEmail": {
                            "query": "Richard",
                            "slop": 0,
                            "max_expansions": 50,
                            "boost": 1.0
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "match_phrase_prefix": {
                        "firstname": {
                            "query": "Richard",
                            "slop": 0,
                            "max_expansions": 50,
                            "boost": 1.0
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            "adjust_pure_negative": true,
            "boost": 1.0
        }
    }
}
```

The response comes as 5 records with different country Ids:

```
[
    {
        "firstname": "Richard Maxwell",
        "mobile": 23523453,
        "primaryEmail": "richard.maxwell@hotmail.com",
        "profileVisibility": null,
        "thumbnail": null,
        "updatedBy": null,
        "countryCode": "16539",
        "status":"Active"
    },
    {
        "firstname": "Richard James",
        "mobile": 23523453,
        "primaryEmail": "richard.james@hotmail.com",
        "profileVisibility": null,
        "thumbnail": null,
        "updatedBy": null,
        "countryCode": "92383",
        "status":"Active"
    },
    {
        "firstname": "Richard King",
        "mobile": 23523453,
        "primaryEmail": "srichard.king@hotmail.com",
        "profileVisibility": null,
        "thumbnail": null,
        "updatedBy": null,
        "countryCode": "38764",
        "status":"Active"
    },
    {
        "firstname": "Richard Martyn",
        "mobile": 23523453,
        "primaryEmail": "srichard.martyn@hotmail.com",
        "profileVisibility": null,
        "thumbnail": null,
        "updatedBy": null,
        "countryCode": "92383",
        "status":"Active"
    },
    {
        "firstname": "Richard Jules",
        "mobile": 23523453,
        "primaryEmail": "srichard.jules@hotmail.com",
        "profileVisibility": null,
        "thumbnail": null,
        "updatedBy": null,
        "countryCode": "92383",
        "status":"Active"
    }
]
```

Now if I use a filter for coutryId like

```
{
    "from": 0,
    "size": 250,
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "term": {
                        "countryId": {
                            "value": "92383",
                            "boost": 1.0
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "term": {
                        "status": {
                            "value": "Active",
                            "boost": 1.0
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "match_phrase_prefix": {
                        "primaryEmail": {
                            "query": "Richard",
                            "slop": 0,
                            "max_expansions": 50,
                            "boost": 1.0
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "match_phrase_prefix": {
                        "firstname": {
                            "query": "Richard",
                            "slop": 0,
                            "max_expansions": 50,
                            "boost": 1.0
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            "adjust_pure_negative": true,
            "boost": 1.0
        }
    }
}
```

It works, filters out the record on some of the countryId but it does not work for a single countrId. What can be the possible root cause for this behaviour?

The Elastic search term query should do filtering for a field in all possible scenarios, but strangely it is working for some values of country code and deos not work for a particular country code. Is there an issue with the query or elastic search set up. What could lead to this behaviour?

Comment: In your query you use `countryId` but in your documents you only have `countryCode` — that looks suspicious.